# Extending stay by a day in Schengen region

Tags: visas, schengen, europe

I have a Schengen visa (single entry) which is valid from 22nd September to 30th October. When I had applied, I had written that I plan to leave the Schengen region on 14th (Friday). However, I am planning to extend the stay by a day and leave on 15th. Will this cause a problem?

Comment: How many days are permitted on your visa?

Comment: Does the visa also say how many days it is valid for? There should be a number under "duration of stay" or similar.

Comment: Duration of stay says 24 days.

Comment: Calculating the number of days from 22 September to 14 October = 23 days. So, does this mean I can extend the stay by a day? Even if there's the slightest risk in doing so, I wouldn't want to take it.

Comment: Do they include both, the start date and the end date, when calculating the number of days?

Comment: @user49587 Yes, the arrival and departure days both count. So, if you arrived at 23:59 and left two minutes later, that's a two-day visit.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Does this 2-day visit rule also apply to the short stay visa - see my question
http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/76624/schengen-multiple-visa-c-for-11-days-how-exactly-the-days-are-calculated

Comment: @DmitriZaitsev As far as I'm aware, for any Schengen visa, any part of a calendar day counts as a day.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Is that rule stated in any official website?