# How are days of stay calculated for Schengen visas issued for less than 90 days?

Tags: visas, schengen, italy, eu, 90-180-visa-rules

UPDATE.
Having checked with the embassy, it appears that they have used the number I put in the form as "intended days of stay" that I have calculated to 9 + 2 = 11 days as any hotel stay or car rental would do, namely simply subtracting the numbers. Never on earth could I think they put it as the hard day limit inside the visa, leaving me with no flexibility and literally putting me at risk to become "illegal" with any small disruption.

---

When applying for an Italian (Schengen) visa,
I have declared trips to Italy from September 2 to 11 and from September 30 to October 2, and have received the multiple type C schengen visa but only for 11 days! Which presumes they have calculated 9 + 2 for the trips I declared.

However, the site http://www.schengen-calculator.com/
calculates both entry and exit days,
so for the above dates as declared I would get 10 + 3 = 13 days,
which would make their calculation wrong.

But that site only refers to the 90 days visa.
It does not let me enter the 11 days C visa.
So their calculation is different for that visa?

Is there any reliable site giving clear information
about how precisely the days are calculated, that I can use in my case?

Comment: An interesting question. My first comment would have been "they made an error at the embassy". But then again, in the documentation of the **official** days calculator, it is stated that "The calculator does not
support the calculation of stay against the authorised stay indicated on the visa sticker, if this period is shorter than 90 days within 180 days and against the validity of the visa." - There is probably a reason for this...

Comment: The consulate appears to have made a mistake. They may have overlooked your second period of intended stay, or they may have failed to calculate each period correctly, as you suspect. I would start by trying to get in touch with them to ask whether they've made a mistake, pointing out that the visa they issued won't allow you to realize the travel plans you applied with. Have you tried that?

Comment: @DCTLib I think the reason is that it can't compare the calculated days of presence against any value other than *90,* and that the method for calculating days of presence is the same.

Comment: @phoog Please see the Update. It appears they didn't pay much attention to the itinerary but more to my (wrongly) calculated "intended period" that they put (to my distress) exactly as the maximum of days.

Answer (score 6):

No, there isn't a special date calculation method for non-90 day visas. Each time you cross an external border, you should get a stamp with a date on it. The day you got an entry stamp, the day you got an exit stamp and every day between them count as one day towards the limit of your visa.

The Schengen [Handbook for processing of visa applications](http://ec.europa.eu/home-affairs/policies/borders/docs/c_2010_1620_en.pdf) has a related example:

> A third country national holding a single entry visa valid for 20 days (10.11.-30.11.2010)
>   and allowing for 5 days of stay enters on 10.11 in Poland, where he stays until the
>   15.11.2010. Subsequently, holding a single entry visa valid for 60 days (8.3.-8.5.2011)
>   allowing for a stay of 45 days he enters Spain on 8.3.2011 and stays until 21.4.2011.

Your options are:

1. Contact the consulate and ask them to amend your visa
2. Change your itinerary for a shorter stay

Comment: Since this became active I noticed that the quoted example seems to contradict the first paragraph (which is how I would count days too). E.g. I think a visa valid from 10.11 to 30.11 is valid for 21 days, while a stay from 10.11 to 15.11 is a 6 day stay. If there is no agreement on how to do arithmetic it is a mystery how there could be agreement on anything else.

Comment: @Dennis their example is slightly off but the rule is perfectly consistent, there is nothing vague about it