# Duration of stay on Schengen visa

Tags: indian-citizens, schengen-visas, visa-expiration

Indian citizen. I have been granted a 6-month multi-entry Schengen visa by the Spanish embassy in Dublin. However, the duration of stay is mentioned as 40. I don't know what that means. I thought we are allowed to stay 90 days in a 180-day period. Does duration here refer to continuous stay, meaning I cannot stay in Schengen continuously for more than 40 days, and before it exceeds 40, I should exit and re-enter again? Please advise.

Comment: What itinerary did you submit? Related question https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/76624/how-are-days-of-stay-calculated-for-schengen-visas-issued-for-less-than-90-days

Comment: I submitted 4 number of  5 days trip spread across 6 months. Maybe that's why they only gave 40 days?

Comment: Well, on the face of it that itinerary certainly doesn’t seem to justify a 90/180 day duration

Comment: It's an unusual combination (in most cases they will either deliver single or dual entry visas with a limited number of days, or multiple entry visas with only the 90/180 limit), but for some reason they felt compelled to deliver this. Is this you first Schengen visa?

Comment: @jcaron the visa code specifies that any visa issued for longer than six months must show "90" for the duration of stay (which as you know means that the traveler is subject to the 90/180 rule).  For a visa of six months or shorter it's not particularly surprising that the granted duration is based on the actual travel plans.  Since there's no limiting entries to a number higher than 2, it has to be a multiple entry visa in this case.

Comment: Doesn't it mean that it's 90 days single entry within a window of 180 days and similar would apply to the 40 days? 40 days single entry

Comment: @jcaron it's my second

Comment: @GauravTaparia the duration given on the visa is the total number of days you can be in tbe Schengen area during the life of the visa, if its period of validity is 180 days or shorter.  If the period of validity is longer than 180 days then the duration is 90 days, and this means that you can be in the Schengen area for no more than 90 days in any 180-day period.  With your 40-day visa, your first visit can be up to 40 days long.  If you don't use all 40 days but instead stay for X days, you can make a second visit whose maximum duration is 40-X days.

Answer (score 6):

You can stay for a **total** of 40 days during the validity of the visa. For example, one trip of 40 days, or two trips of 20 days each, or three of 25 days/5 days/10 days.

From [How to read the visa sticker](https://home-affairs.ec.europa.eu/how-read-visa-sticker_en)

> DURATION OF STAY………DAYS indicates the number of days you may stay in the Schengen area. The days should be counted from the date you enter the Schengen area (the entry stamp) to the date you exit the Schengen area (the exit stamp), i.e. both days included.

Comment: Also: should the duration field be empty (or contains '---'') then that is the same as if it contains 90.